# How does a Drivechain output work?

Tags: output, sidechains, drivechains

It is said that Drivechain works by sending a transaction output to a miner/hashrate-controlled escrow. I know it works by allowing miners to vote over a large number of blocks on transactions, that want to spend from these outputs. Only after a transaction has acquired a number of votes can it be published.

However, how is that supposed to work practically in Script? Is there a new proposed opcode like `OP_CHECKTRANSACTIONHASENOUGHVOTESVERIFY` or something like that?